# Unity catalog at Azure synapse for data governance

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, azure-synapse, databricks-unity-catalog

There are lot of stuff available online setting up Unity Catalog on Azure Databricks.

unfortunately I did not find anything related to, setting up Unity catalog via Azure Synapse.

My use case is:

- I am using Delta table model for big data on Azure synapse. And saving all flat files and delta tables on ADLS gen2.
- I want to secure my flat files and delta table by implementing access control  to each members.

Its straight forward in case of Databricks: Create Metastore then catalog. But this option i did not find in Synapse.

If any one has idea about securing delta tables in synapse. It would be great help. Regards

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unity Catalog is used for data governance for Databricks that can enforce data access checks. Recently there was an announcement about [Hive Metastore interface](https://www.databricks.com/blog/extending-databricks-unity-catalog-open-apache-hive-metastore-api) that could be potentially used with Synapse via [external Hive Metastore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-external-metastore), but this functionality is still in the private preview.